# Can't find mdb ejb3

Tags: eclipse, jboss, redhat, drools-kie-server

where I can find mdb ejb3 to add this code:

I have been searched in `jboss redhat 7.2` and founding yet!

**code:**

```
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra}"/>
    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
```

Any help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messaging implementation changed from HornetQ to ActiveMQ in JBoss EAP 7.  In your standalone-full.xml file, you will find:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
```